# Reverse for 'sending_message' not found. 'sending_message' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I have an app called com when I try to access viewing_user template which contains a form with action to another view get the error above

this is urls.py

```
app_name = 'com'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<name>[\w\-]+)/$',views.viewing_user, name='viewing_user'),

]
```

this is the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your views here.
RECEIVER_ID = 0
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'com/index.html',{})

def viewing_user(request, name):
    #username = request.GET.get('username','')
    try:
        User_obj = User.objects.get(username = name)
        RECEIVER_ID = User_obj.id
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        User_obj = None

    return render(request, 'com/viewing_user.html',{'u':name,'obj':User_obj})


def sending_message(request):
    form = MessageForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            message = message_form.save(commit = False)
            message.date = datetime.date.now()
            message.from_user = user.id
            message._to = RECEIVER_ID
            message.save()

        else:
            print form.errors
    return render(request, 'com/viewing_user.html', {'form':form})
```

this is the template vieweing_user.html which seems that has a problem in the action of the form

```
<html>

  {% if obj == None %}

    <h2>Sorry this user ({{u}}) DoesNotExist</h2>

  {% else %}
    <h3>Be honest, and Tellme what you want</h3>
    <br>
      <i>{{obj.username}}</i>

      <form method="post" action="{%url 'com:sending_message' %}">
        {%csrf_token%}
        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields%}
          {{hidden}}
        {%endfor%}

        {% for visible in form.visible_fields%}
        {{visible}}
        {%endfor%}

        <input type="submit" value='Tell'/>
      </form>

  {%endif%}

</html>
```

Comment: You don't have a URL pattern called "sending_message".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reverse tries to look for its parameter value in urlpatterns. You do not have any url pattern with name `sending_message` in `com` namespace.

You would want to create an url pattern with name `sending_message`

`url(r'^(?Psomepattern)/$',views.sending_message, name='sending_message'),`

Comment: glad I could help